# Sort Steam games by number of reviews

Tags: steam

Is it possible to sort the entirety of all Steam games by number of reviews? Not to be confused with percentage rating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steam doesn't have the functionality for that, but you can use 3rd party sites like SteamDB to process that for you, such as [this search](https://steamdb.info/stats/gameratings/).

[image]